# nomad consul traefik https

Tags: subdomain, lets-encrypt, consul, nomad

I have a go app that i need to run multiple instances under separate subdomains, i have a working nomad consul setup and got the go app to run and is accessible via a fixed ip address and dedicated port. But i am stuck on how to make it work with the unique subdomains and working https.

So what i'm looking for is like
app1 runs on https://app1.example.com
app2 runs on https://app2.example.com
I tried to use traefic (got it running as a job), DNSmasq but i havent got the above to work.

Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traefik supports integrating with Consul through its [Consul Catalog](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/consul-catalog/) provider. See https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/nomad/load-balancing-traefik for an example of how to configure this when running Traefik on Nomad.

The example in that tutorial configures the tag `traefik.http.routers.http.rule=Path('/myapp')` on the service so that requests for `/myapp` are routed to the backend service instance. In your case, you'll need  to modify this to match on the HTTP Host header so that you can route subdomains to different services. For example:

```
tags = [
  "traefik.enable=true",
  "traefik.http.routers.http.rule=Host(`app1.example.com`)",
]
```

See https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule for a full list of supported rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i must say i provided more info, since i posted my message here https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/go-app-with-https-nomand-consul-traefik/35401/9,

Comment: and i got it to work. It is along the same lines as the answer you provided

Comment: What gets me stuck now is that i cant get the app to react to both port 8080 and port 1935. The 8080 reacts but not 1935